# Calling service from self host

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a very complex scenario in which my services are dynamically loaded and everything is done programmatically.  In particular I have a service that has 2 endpoints

> net.pip://localhost/test
>   net.pipe://localhost/test/mex

I have a client that access this without issue as well as the WCF Test Client tool.

I am trying to access the service from the selfhost wrapper.  I have read you just treat it as a client and create a factory and channel but something is preventing this from working.  The same code that works on the client will not work in the wrapper.  The code just

```
    private IAgentBase GetLocalClient(string serviceEndpointName)
    {
        var factory = new ChannelFactory<IAgentBase>(serviceEndpointName);
        return factory.CreateChannel();
    }
```

This does return a proxy and then I call a method on the service...

```
    var proxy = GetLocalClient("net.pipe://localhost/test");
    proxy.DoThis();
```

But the code just goes someplace  - keeps running and no error.  The statement never completes.  When I step over that line or set a BP or a try catch, it never completes the method call

Answer (score 0):

Change your GetLocalClient to the following

```
 public IAgentBase GetlocalClient(string ed)
    {
         EndpointAddress edi = new EndpointAddress(ed);
        var channel = ChannelFactory<IAgentBase>.CreateChannel(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), edi);
        return channel;
    }
```

Comment: I tried - Same thing.  What happens is it times out but doesn't offer any more info than that.